# Show user friendly message on EC2 console if policy restricts instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have written a policy to enforce two tags test1 and test2. The policy restricts creation of new instances without these tags but it shows an encrypted error message which does not make any sense. 
Can anything be done to show a human readable message on console.
I know that this message can be decrypted using decode-authorization-message command. But I need it on console.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help regarding this.

Below is an example encrypted message which appears:
Launch Failed
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: wyWMRRNJslkE3dIzT904iPcUWBkqUn7wg_Rv893pq-P6PTcp_pC3E8SU-POmDKIn_eQQ4IuRbK6JI7PyjPRpxiY8xkFGUDVk-f1nQeCLRMFmLpHals4tim5udAPqQ7uVV2Wl2yKzvq0V5p82ih_YII0y1lPh5QsUIMOfgdBiaJ0tkm5M91VYRGbbOaQtrcoHTyNEhMg2GSB-0Gtr887nrUwtJ8i7pWNNNjP4NuxR3C93fhRQB9TeDqf5NjTTQxLrjf3TqFn5YXJ16Bdd7G9973meAJIc-NEXeCzDzrEAJkqQAHX5gxFi3Iy58OlIxwWo4hjWxYkA71wpg0wMu-tUGt2v-i70ic2p31CKl3eGa1uOSNaRI87dz2danSv6mvMz2Wb-PGs3FztwahHyyrailoJu2o1hoAEzO8T0S3b5eYps-a1NuEKwgyyy7eYznaWDFO30rXQefQS_UW1wcNoU1MYEkfrW5c5yYeZYgUtys6spcyfRu9YiP57ji3FS4CWubOWiyb78mzvgWTpuXropM3UqJO8I_iYt5b1VTN_UwjFriGedM3VmnoZ9o-iSdLl7H2oFDzk9mX3HUcLH11VIxkQnBk_jry6W1_ADbn8uPfVKszCzwpC-KhRNMZbUf33IpeOsU17hxh1UVG8eGD

Comment: This is standard practice at AWS. The error message may contain security sensitive information. Only users with rights to decode the message can see the details.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be done. You could show a user-friendly message if creating the instance via custom shell or python scripts.

Or if you strictly want to use console, you could consider asking users to create instances via pre-configured templates. That should not throw up such errors.